# Making comparable identifier in R

Tags: r

I am using R 3.1.3 and I have data like this;

```
id_1 <- c('a','a','b','c','d','e')
id_2 <- c('a','f','f','g','g','e')
```

and I want to make data like;

```
id_common <- c('1','1','1','2','2','3')
```

The situation is that we have data in period 1 and 2 with different administrative boarders (`id_1` and `id_2`) because of splits or mergers during these periods and we want to generate a new boarder identifier to make them comparable by the aggregation using the new identifier (`id_common`). In this case for example,  a part of `a` was merged with `b` and became `f` between these periods, so I want to treat `a` and `b` in period 1 and `a` and `f` in period 2 as one group named `1` and aggregate both periods' data at this level to compare.

Of course, `id_common` should be the most precise ID to cover both periods (It should not be `id_common <- c('1','1','1','1','1','3')`). Is there any good idea to do this easily?

In fact, I have more than two periods in my data, but I think I can modify your suggested strategy to the case of more than two periods easily.

Thank you in advance,

Follow up;

I think I could do this by the following code, but this might be a bit messy. (I made string based `id_common` for labeling.)

```
id_common <- id_1
elements <- unique(id_common)
for (element in elements){
   map1 <- vector()
   map1 <- id_2[id_1==element]
   map2 <- id_1[which(id_2  %in% map1)]
   if (setequal(map2,element) == F){
      while (setequal(map2,element) == T){
         map1 <- vector()
         map1 <- id_2[which(id_1  %in% map2)]
         map2 <- id_1[which(id_2  %in% map1)]
         }
      }
   id_common[which(id_1  %in% map2)]<- paste(unique(map2),collapse="+")
}
```

Comment: Ok, then I didn't understand what you are really after

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are saying that regions `a`, `b`, and `f` correspond to region `1`. `c`, `d`, and `g` correspond to `2`, and `e` corresponds to `3`.

One simple way to do this is to make a list and then stack the list and then merge the data frame with both ids:

```
id_key = list(`1`=c('a','b','f'), `2`=c('c','d','g'), `3`=c('e'))
stack_id <- stack(id_key)
```

Then you can merge with this data frame which acts as the key.

Comment: Sorry for my confusing question, 

Yes, I wanted to do your suggested code after generating `key`, but the point is my data is massively large and very inefficient to categorize their ids into groups such as 1, 2, and 3 by hand. So, my question is how to make groups (in this case, elements of the list) from `id_1` and `id_2` automatically.

Comment: How would you determine the mapping of old keys to new keys?

Comment: By the position of `id_1` and `id_2`, such as area in the 5th position was called as `d` in period 1 and `g` in period 2. Finally I could find out some way to solve this as I wrote in "follow up" so please check it if you are interested in. Thank you!